# How to prove the change in Lagrangian is related to divergence of Noether current?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

In Paul Langacker's [The Standard Model and Beyond](http://sns.ias.edu/~pgl/SMB/), equation 3.50 states that, for a Lagrangian $\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{L}_0 + \mathcal{L}_1$, where $\left[ T^i , \mathcal{L}_0 \right] = 0$ and $\left[ T^i , \mathcal{L}_1 \right] \ne 0$, we would have

$$
\mathcal{L}' - \mathcal{L} = \left[ - \mathrm{i} \beta ^i T^i , \mathcal{L}_1 \right] = - \beta ^i \partial ^{\mu} J_{\mu}^i
$$

For $J_{\mu}^i$ defined as following

$$
J_{\mu}^i = - \mathrm{i} \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \partial^{\mu} \Phi _a} L_{a b}^i \Phi _b - \mathrm{i} \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \partial^{\mu} \Phi _a^{\dagger}} \left( - L_{a b}^{i *} \right) \Phi _b^{\dagger}
$$

I completely have no clue on how to prove the second equality in the first equation, could anyone help me on that?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56851/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110209/2451 and links therein.